# Prestashop : sharing products on instagram

Tags: prestashop-1.6, sharing

I want to add a button to share products on instagram.

the socialsharing module contain only facebook , twitter, google and pinterest button

Is it possible to add instagram using js or... Is it possible to do that ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but it needs an answer for anyone looking for a solution.

Instagram does not allow uploading media from a 3rd party website.
As per their media endpoints, only GET methods are allowed:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Also, you can check this answer too:
[Instagram: Share photo from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673156/instagram-share-photo-from-webpage)