# In php, I am using page sharing option in my website with multiple social media option, i am not getting how to share page on instagram?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**PHP OR Codeigniter:**

I am using page sharing option in my website with multiple social media option, i am not getting how to share page on instagram?

I am using page sharing with multiple social medias with following code:

```
<?php
$url = urlencode($curr_url);
$imgurl = urlencode($curr_img_url);
?>

Share on social media:
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">share on facebook with new tab</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">share on twitter with new tab</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">share on google-plus with new tab</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&media=<?php echo $imgurl; ?>&description=Corn Paneer Sandwich" target="_blank">share on pin with new tab</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank">share on linkedin with new tab</a>
```

**But for Instagram I am not getting any code.. to share page on instagram?**

please suggest me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram: Share photo from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673156/instagram-share-photo-from-webpage)

Comment: what about link sharing on instagram??