# Instagram API: how to post photo directly using JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, instagram, instagram-api

I am working on an Angular (2 or 4) project where requires to share images/photos on Instagram.

I read one answer about it. [Instagram: Share photo from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673156/instagram-share-photo-from-webpage)

But it's a very old answer, I hope Instagram has recently updated something with their API, or people out there have workarounds for this.

My question is how can I post image/photo to Instagram directly with JavaScript/TypeScript?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Nope, still no endpoint defined in their API docs.

Comment: I heard that people somehow make it with server-side, anyone know any workaround, please share it here.

Comment: a quick search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844706/how-to-post-pictures-to-instagram-using-api