# Sharing with Instagram Story with URL, like spotify and netflix?

Tags: react-native, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

I am researching about sharing with Instagram Story with URL, like spotify and netflix. Is there any way to do that, the solutions I found can not share with URL.

[image]

Comment: This help right here may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893635/14465558

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get this working?