# How can I make an Instagram deep link to open Instagram and profile story with a custom data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, deep-linking

I would let my app users to share image to their Instagram. How can I do it? Reading this article, but not clear: https://pureoxygenlabs.com/step-by-step-creating-deep-links-to-instagram-hashtags-to-increase-mobile-engagement/

Can I use this url scheme to share form a web app? `instagram-stories://share?source_application=`

If yes, how can I pass the data itself? Following this docs, it comes here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories

```
Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.parse("your-image-asset-uri-goes-here");
intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG);
```